# Splitting numbers using np.where method with many conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The `np.where` method I wrote turns the prices (Close) into ones and zeros. One for up and zero for down. I need to make this method split the numbers not only into ones and zeros but in 6,5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6 e.g. 6 for a very huge difference in up-direction, 2 for a low difference in up direction, 0 for no difference, -6 for a ver huge difference in down-direction and so on. How can I do that?

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('AUDNZD_Candlestick_1_Hour_BID_12.12.2006-30.10.2021.csv')
df = df.drop(columns=['Local time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume'])
df['Price_Up'] = np.where(df['Close'].shift(1) > df['Close'] ,0,1)
df
```

My output:

| Close Price_Up |
| --- |
| 1.13895 1 |
| 1.13871 0 |
| 1.13772 0 |
| 1.13840 1 |

Comment: the output is a way larger then this. But this is just a sample.

Comment: do deltaPrice = df['Close'].iloc[1:] -df['Close'].iloc[:-1]  then define a scale of high,and low. by example if you need a scale for -6 to 6 and you consider a high delta '1' then you could define `step=1/6` and then do deltaPrice / step for last replace all values `higher than 6` by `6` and the same for lowers than -6 ..

Comment: thank you very much sir. could I get more code about how to define the scale of high and low (maybe just an example). im not really familier with this stuff. A big thank anyway. @UlisesBussi

Comment: I think `pd.cut` would be an easy solution, applied on the difference of the column, and define how many bins you want, as well as the labels being numbers, so something like `pd.cut(df['Close'].diff(), bins=13, labels=range(-6,7))` note that 0 does not mean no difference exactly with this method

Comment: @mathandlogic sorry i wouldnt be able to answer for some hours. maybe 3... then i will make a toy example!  could be great if you put a df['Close'] vector with values (10 or 20? ) to play with, preferible if in the values you have all the span (a point with value 6 and other with negative value) no matter that aren't real values is just to give me some idea

Comment: I will be waiting for you sir. I really appreciate that very much.  let's say  -6 = - 0.003###         -5 = -0.002  ##    -4= -0.001   ###  -3=-0.0005 ## -2= -0.0002  ## -1 = -0.0001    ##  0 = 0  ##and    6 = 0.003    ##     5 = 0.002  ##    4= 0.001    ## 3=0.0005 ## 2= 0.0002 ##  1 = 0.0001 @UlisesBussi

Comment: `deltaPrice = df['Close'].iloc[1:] -df['Close'].iloc[:-1]
moin = pd.cut(df['Close'].diff(), bins=13, labels=range(-6,7)) `    these lines of code turned my numbers into -1 and -2  and by the element number 0 of the list it shows now "NaN"

Comment: I tried it with the values `pd.cut(df['Close'].diff(), bins=25, labels=range(-12,13))`  and it showed me values between +1 and -6

Comment: I Like the pd.cut solution... seems a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was harder than I thougth:

1. Create a value vector to work with (containing a lot of posible changes)
2. Calculate diff by index
3. cut in bins
4. plotting results
5. and 2)

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # idk if i need this
    import numpy as np #to be sure..
    
    #this create values increasing and then decreasing spaning varios steps
    positive_steps = np.arange(0,0.003,0.00005)
    negative_steps = np.arange(0,-0.003,-0.00005)
    
    values = 1 + np.concatenate([positive_steps.cumsum(),
                             positive_steps.sum()+negative_steps.cumsum()])
    
    
    #create dataframe and get change column
    df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['Close'])
    df['Change'] = df['Close'].diff()
```

3. 

```
#maximun range
maxRange = 0.003
span = 2*maxRange
nDivs =12 #not counting 0 bc i will define special case for it

zero_tol = 0.0001 #special case theshold    

scores = np.zeros(len(df))
for i, val in enumerate(df['Change'][1:],1):
    if abs(val)<zero_tol: #tolerance for rank 0 is a small value
        scores[i] = 0
    else:
        score= int(val*nDivs/span) #calculate score
        if score>nDivs/2: #saturation of scores bigger  than 6
            score = nDivs
        elif score<-nDivs/2: #saturation of smallers
            score = -nDivs
        scores[i] = score

#asignate score
df['Score'] = scores
```

4. check results

```
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(3,1,1)
    plt.plot(df['Close'])
    plt.subplot(3,1,2)
    plt.plot(df['Change'])
    plt.subplot(3,1,3)
    plt.plot(df['Score'])
```

[image: the plot results]

---

***EDIT***

You can get a similar result without that much code using `np.digitize`. You onlu have to define your bins and then call the function over `df['Change']`

```
# optional you can define the bins the way you want or with an arange
#bins=  [-0.003,-0.002,-0.001, -0.0005,-0.0002, -0.0001, 0, 
#        0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.002,  0.003]
bins = np.arange(-0.003,0.003,span/nDivs)
inds = np.digitize(df['Change'], bins,right=False)
numpyScores = inds - 7
```

Comment: that's really awesome. It is litterly what I need. Thank you a lot once again.

Comment: Check it out, you can change the `span`, `zero_tol ` or `nDivs` to get other results. Today (here's other day) I see that and think that there be a "quantize" in some library to get the same result...

Comment: perfect!! May I ask how you can find these methods? @Ulises Bussi

Comment: wich methods? the first one is one proposed by me (this time, i did not make a full research yo check if there's a name for this method). The second one is just ussage of `numpy.digitize`

Comment: I mean the second one. What does make you able to find it  (np.digitize) and me not? I wasted a lot of time to find this method (np.digitize) but all my tries were not successful! @Ulises Bussi

Comment: ohhh sorry you have to include `numpy` library : `import numpy as np`. Here `np` is the common alias (shorter than writing the whole name of the library). Last thing it's seems that `pandas.cut` does exactly the same that `numpy.digitize`

Comment: yea I knew this. But thanks anyway, you are a great men :)

Comment: could you please tell me why you choose the -7 in `numpyScores = inds - 7` @Ulises Bussi

Comment: To put values from range [1,13] (generated by np.digitize) to range [-6,6] as toy wanted....